# Android: Internet works in emulator but not on my phone

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I'm making an app which reads a certain part of a website and posts it to the screen. The app currently works in my android emulator but when I transfer it to my galaxy S2, it doesn't seem to access the website at all.

```
package com.example.beam;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.*;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String current = null;
Button check;
TextView text;
TextView url;
String[] lines = new String[12];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkstatus);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    url = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.url);

    String[] lines = new String[12];

    check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Attempt to the read the source from a website.
            String bodyHtml = "null";
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new       HttpGet("http://www.spring8.or.jp/ext/ja/status/text.html");
            ResponseHandler<String> resHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

            try {
                bodyHtml = httpClient.execute(httpGet, resHandler);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            double current = 0;
            try{
            String derp = bodyHtml.substring(bodyHtml.lastIndexOf("mA") - 5, bodyHtml.lastIndexOf("mA"));
            current = Double.parseDouble(derp);
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
            url.setText(current + " mA");


        }
    });
}
```

}

Apologies if the coding is a bit poor and messy, I'm quite new to all this. How do I fix this issue? Thank you

Also, I'm pretty sure I've set the permission correctly in the manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....

Its a good practice to Keep the UI work on UI thread and Non-UI work on Non-UI thread, but that became a **LAW from the release of HONEYCOMB Android version**.... That may be causing the error.

So you can do the following....

1. Do the Http on a separate thread, and then place the value on the UI using **Handler**, Handler Keep the reference of the thread in which it was created.
2. You can use **AsyncTask** which is specially designed for android to make a sync between
   UI and Non-UI thread.

Note:

Please check the Internet Permission in AndroidManifest, though i know you have done it, cause the app ran on the emulator.... but still..no harm in checking it again.

Comment: Thank you, I found an example on the internet which made use of AsyncTask and it worked!